# wso2is tenant management problem when add new tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I using the service endpoint `TenantMgtAdminService.TenantMgtAdminServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/`
with the method `addTenant` in wso2is 5.9.0

I have the error:

```xml
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Error in adding claims to the user.</soapenv:Text>
```

and in other ocassiones this error:

```xml
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Error in notifying tenant addition.</soapenv:Text>
```

This is my soapenv:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://beans.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:addTenant>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:tenantInfoBean>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:active>true</xsd:active>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:admin>admin@abc.com</xsd:admin>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:adminPassword>admin</xsd:adminPassword>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:createdDate></xsd:createdDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:email>admin@abc.com</xsd:email>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:firstname>firstname</xsd:firstname>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:lastname>lastname</xsd:lastname>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:originatedService></xsd:originatedService>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:successKey></xsd:successKey>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:tenantDomain>mydomain.com</xsd:tenantDomain>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:tenantId>1</xsd:tenantId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:usagePlan></xsd:usagePlan>
         </ser:tenantInfoBean>
      </ser:addTenant>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I used the same saop request you pointed here to create tenant in WSO2 IS5.9.0 and It was success.  Are there any error logs in the backend? Can you please share the carbon logs also?

Comment: Hello, here you are the logs i hope can you help me.
https://pastebin.com/Chf3wchC

Comment: Can you try with a new tenantDomain and tenantId, the error seems to be there is already an entry available in the database for this specific tenant